# R:tidyverse select column values and copy them under other column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I encountered an issue after bind_rows several dfs like the one below

```
df <- data.frame(sites     = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b","c", "a", "b","c"),
             name      = c("x1", "x1", "x1", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x4", "x4", "x4"),
             compound1 = c("10", "10", "10", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA" ), 
             compound2 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "15", "15","15", "NA", "NA", "NA",  "NA", "NA", "NA"), 
             compound3 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "20", "25", "30",  "NA", "NA", "NA"),
             compound4 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "40", "22", "23"))
```

Basically I would like to have the following output

```
df2 <- data.frame(sites   c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b","c", "a", "b","c"),
             name       = c("x1", "x1", "x1", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x4", "x4", "x4"),
             conc      = c("10", "10", "10", "15", "15","15","20", "25", "30", "40", "22", "23"))
```

That is, only three column (sites, name, and new column conc) and all values under the column "conc"

I am bit lost about how to do it and I´ll appreciate your feedback. Better if your help uses tidyverse.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way. We can first replace `"NA"` with `NA`, and then use `coalesce`.

```
library(dplyr)

df_out <- df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("compound"), .fns = function(x){
    x2 <- ifelse(x %in% "NA", NA_character_, x)
    return(x2)
  })) 

df_comp <- df_out %>%
  select(starts_with("compound")) %>% 
  as.list.data.frame()

df_out <- df_out %>%
  mutate(conc = coalesce(!!!df_comp)) %>%
  select(-starts_with("compound"))

df_out
#    sites name conc
# 1      a   x1   10
# 2      b   x1   10
# 3      c   x1   10
# 4      a   x2   15
# 5      b   x2   15
# 6      c   x2   15
# 7      a   x3   20
# 8      b   x3   25
# 9      c   x3   30
# 10     a   x4   40
# 11     b   x4   22
# 12     c   x4   23
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `invoke`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
   transmute(sites, name, conc = invoke(coalesce, select(., starts_with('compound'))))
#   sites name conc
#1      a   x1   10
#2      b   x1   10
#3      c   x1   10
#4      a   x2   15
#5      b   x2   15
#6      c   x2   15
#7      a   x3   20
#8      b   x3   25
#9      c   x3   30
#10     a   x4   40
#11     b   x4   22
#12     c   x4   23
```

Comment: Excelent! quite fast! although I dont understand very well the function of "type.convert" here

Comment: @PedrNton It changes the column data types based on the values.  Your input data have string "NA" instead of `NA` that converted the compound colums to character.  AFter type.convert, it converts to numeric

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

1 - since your columns are character strings, it's not actually interpreting the NA values as NA, but rather as strings "NA". I would convert them to numeric so the numbers are numbers and the NAs are actually NA.

2 - Use coalesce!

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("compound"), as.numeric)) %>%
  mutate(conc = coalesce(compound1, compound2, compound3, compound4))
```

And using your example, that works for me!